# How to add a non-user-editable field to a content type in Strapi?

Tags: strapi

Say I have a `post` content type with the following 4 fields:

- `title` (string)
- `content` (string)
- `slug` (string)
- `author` (relationship)

How can I add a 5th field that depends on one of the above 4 fields for its value and isn't user-editable? Say, I wanted a `wordCount` field with the number of words in the `content` field as its value. What file should I consider exploring in order to incorporate this functionality?

P.S.: For what it's worth, I'm using MongoDB Atlas for my database needs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will have to create your `wordCount` attribute in your content type.

Then in the **content manager** link in the left menu, you will be able to custom the view of your edit/create page. Here you will be able to **Disable** or **Remove** the field from the page.

After that you will have to go in the `./api/post/models/Post.js` file and update following functions.

If you are using NoSQL database (Mongo)

```
beforeSave: async (model) => {
  if (model.content) {
    model.wordCount = model.content.length;
  }
},
beforeUpdate: async (model) => {
  if (model.getUpdate().content) {
    model.update({
      wordCount:  model.getUpdate().content.length
    });
  }
},
```

If you are using SQL (SQLite, Postgres, MySQL)

```
beforeSave: async (model, attrs, options) => {
  if (attrs.content) {
    attrs.wordCount = attrs.content.length;
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

*(For Strapi 3.x; NoSQL and SQL)*

1. Create a wordcount field on the content type
2. Configure the view of the content type and click on the wordcount field - set 'Editable field' to false.
3. Edit *./api/post/models/post.js*

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  lifecycles: {
    async beforeCreate(data) {
      data.wordcount = data.content.match(/(\w+)/g).length;
    },
    async beforeUpdate(params, data) {
      data.wordcount = data.content.match(/(\w+)/g).length;
    },
  },
};
```