# Change / validate properties before insert or update

Tags: strapi

I am trying to do some custom validation / sanitization on the data before insert and update.
I thought the model's lifecycle callbacks are a good place to this kind of work:

```
module.exports = {
  // Before saving a value.
  // Fired before an `insert` or `update` query.
  beforeSave: async (model) => {
    console.log('[beforeSave]', 'model', model)
    // Do something here with the model
  },

  // Before creating a value.
  // Fired before an `insert` query.
  beforeCreate: async (model) => {
    console.log('[beforeCreate]', 'model', model)
    // Do something here with the model
  },

  // Before updating a value.
  // Fired before an `update` query.
  beforeUpdate: async (model) => {
    console.log('[beforeUpdate]', 'model', model)
    // Do something here with the model
  }
};
```

When I insert a new record the `beforeSave` and `beforeCreate` methods both get called. The model in this case is the new object I want to insert.

When I update a record the `beforeSave` method does not get called, the `beforeUpdate` method gets called but the model is not the object I want to save. In this case the model is a `Query` object.

Is this the best place to this validation?

If so how can I modify the object before update?

I am using Strapi v3.0.0-beta.16.3 with MongoDB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I suggest you to manage your life cycle.
Example to manage slug

```
// const slugify = require('slugify');

beforeSave: async (model) => {
  if (model.title) {
    model.slug = slugify(model.title);
  }
},
beforeUpdate: async (model) => {
  if (model.getUpdate().title) {
    model.update({
      slug:  slugify(model.getUpdate().title)
    });
  }
},
```

For SQL connections this would be the option:

```
beforeSave: async (model) => {
  if (model.get('title')) {
    model.set({slug: slugify(model.get('title'))});
  }
},
```

Comment: Would this be the right place to add custom validation? e.g. ````const validTitles = new Set(['a', 'b', 'c']);
if (!validTitles.has(model.title)) throw new Error('invalid title!')````

Comment: Is this code still valid for Strapi v3? Although it's in the docs I'm getting this

`TypeError: model.getUpdate is not a function`

EDIT- I saw your answer here which solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55339252/1259863